# CMake problem of linking with headers included of the form <src/header.h>

Tags: linker, cmake

I quite new with CMake, but I have a problem with porting an existing library to it.
In order to simplify, I will only work on 2 files : angle.cpp and angle.h.
The files are this ones :

```
/cmaketest/CMakeLists
/cmaketest/src/angle.cpp
/cmaketest/src/angle.h
```

and I will run CMake and produce the Makefile in /cmaketest/.

My CMakeLists is currently this one :

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(cmaketest)

SET(cmaketest_SRCDIR src)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(${cmaketest_SRCDIR} cmaketest_SOURCES)
FILE(GLOB cmaketest_HEADERS ${cmaketest_SRCDIR}/*.h )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(cmaketest ${cmaketest_SOURCES} ${cmaketest_HEADERS})
```

But the problem is that in angle.cpp, the header is included not by `"angle.h"` but by `<src/angle.h>`

So with the current cmake file I got the following error when I execute make :

> /cmaketest/src/angle.cpp:1:23: fatal error: src/angle.h: file not found

How to solve the problem ? (for backward compatibility I can't modify `<src/angle.h>` in the .cpp file)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the project directory as an include directory by using the [include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainclude_directories) command:

```
...
file (GLOB cmaketest_HEADERS ${cmaketest_SRCDIR}/*.h )

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
add_executable(cmaketest ${cmaketest_SOURCES} ${cmaketest_HEADERS})
```